# How to save the selected value from dropdownlist to database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

In my one of the view I add a dropdown and I bind this drop down with my database like this..

```
public ActionResult PostMarks()
{
    JoinMod std = new JoinMod();
    std.Drp_bind = (from nm in db.TbStudent
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = nm.StudentName,
                        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)nm.StudentId).Trim()
                    }).ToList<SelectListItem>();

    return View(std);
}
```

Here is the dropdownlist in my view

```
<p>StudentName</p>
    @Html.DropDownList("StudentName",Model.Drp_bind,"Select")
```

And on `Post` I am trying to save the data into the database like this

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult PostMarks(Marks marks)
 {
    db.TbMarks.Add(marks);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ShowAllMarks");
 }
```

Now when I check my database after save data in database the Id save in the database is zero from the dropdownlist. Please experts help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be using @HTML.DropDownListFor, specifying a lambda that indicates which property in your model you want to bind the list's selected value to on the POST.

Given a view model like so:

```
public class MarksViewModel 
{
    public Marks Marks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Drp_bind { get; set; }
}
```

The drop down list in the CSHTML can be declared like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Marks.StudentId, m.Drp_bind, "Select a Student")
```

The first argument is an expression describing the property on your model that you want to populate with the selected value from the drop down list in the post back. The second is the list comprising the values to which we need to data bind.

Note that your CSHTML will need more form fields within it bound to the other properties of the `Marks` property.

Your POST method would now take `MarksViewModel` as an argument and extract the `Marks` property from it to add to the DbContext for saving.

Comment: how to specify lambda expression for this type of databinding I am trying to use lambda but my dropdownlist shows me empty like this I am using

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Drp_bind,new List<SelectListItem>())

Comment: I have edited to give a fuller answer. It's still not been near a real compiler, mind, so excuse any issues.